# HDFS File System - How to get the byte count for a specific file in a directory

Tags: java, hdfs

I am trying to get the byte count for the specific file in a HDFS directory.

I tried to use `fs.getFileStatus()` ,but i do not see any methods for getting byte count of the file, i can see only `getBlockSize()` method.

Is there any way can i get the byte count of a specific file in HDFS?

Answer (score 1):

`fs.getFileStatus()` returns a FileStatus objects which has a method `getLen()` this will return "length of this file, in bytes." Maybe you should haev a closer look on this: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html.

**BUT** be aware that the file size is not that important on HDFS. The files will be organized in so called data-blocks each datablock is by default 64 MB. So if you deal with many small files (which is one big anti-pattern on HDFS) you may have less capacity than you  expect. See this link for more details:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#Data_Blocks

Answer (score 0):

We need to use `fs.getLen()` method to get the file byte count.